# in c++ how do I calculate tool path length?

Tags: visual-c++

I am dealing with generation of tool path where composed many points in three dimension and I am using CNC machine to generate them. One of the things that I want to calculate is tool path length which is defined the total length of path. So I tried this:

```
1.6760 3.7901 6.1955 
1.2788 4.1872 5.3681
0.2832 5.1828 3.2939
0.1835 5.2173 3.0576
0.1097 5.1205 2.8292
0.0815 4.9185 2.6699
0.0812 4.8728 2.6491 
0.0810 4.8270 2.6288 
0.0807 4.7810 2.6089
```

The points are like these.

```
// math.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include<math.h>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

using std::vector;

using std::ostream;
using std::istream;
using std::ifstream;

using std::operator>>;
using std::operator<<;

struct point

{
    float x ;
    float y ;
    float z ;
};

ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const point &p)
{
    out << "(" << p.x << "," << p.y << " ," << p.z << "," << ")";
    return out;
}

istream& operator>> (istream& in, point& point)
{
    in >> point.x >> point.y >> point.z;
    return in;
}

struct line
{
    point start;
    point next;
    float sqDistance()
    {
        float dx = start.x - next.x;
        float dy = start.y - next.y;
        float dz = start.z - next.z;
        double distance = 0.0;
        distance = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy + dz * dz);
        return distance;
    }
};

ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const line &ln)
{
    out << "From " << ln.start << " to " << ln.next;
    return out;
}

istream& operator>> (istream& in, line ln)
{
    cout << "Enter x y z start then x y z  next: ";
    in >> ln.start.x >> ln.start.y >> ln.start.z >>  ln.next.x >> ln.next.y >> ln.next.z;
    return in;
}

int main()
{
    point origin, input;
    line ray;
    vector<line> side;

    // READ POINTS FROM FILE
    ifstream pointfile("concave.txt");
    if (pointfile.is_open())
    {
        pointfile >> origin.x >> origin.y >> origin.z;
        cout << "origin: " << origin << endl;
        ray.start = origin;

        while (pointfile >> ray.next)
        {
            cout
                << " GOTO/ " << ray.next 
                << " The distance from point to the next is : "
                << ray.sqDistance() << endl;

            side.push_back(ray);
        }
    }
    else
        cout << "Unable to open file";
    pointfile.close();



    vector<line>::iterator iter = side.begin();
    line temp, closest = *iter;
    float minimumDistance = closest.sqDistance(), distance = 0.0;

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

-I expect the distance between point and its next point.
-the total length of this line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like this - suppose you want distance between points and not from start (line 93 with comment):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include<math.h>
#include <conio.h>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

using std::vector;

using std::ostream;
using std::istream;
using std::ifstream;

using std::operator>>;
using std::operator<<;

struct point

{
    float x ;
    float y ;
    float z ;
};

ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const point &p)
{
    out << "(" << p.x << "," << p.y << " ," << p.z << "," << ")";
    return out;
}

istream& operator>> (istream& in, point& point)
{
    in >> point.x >> point.y >> point.z;
    return in;
}

struct line
{
    point start;
    point next;
    float sqDistance()
    {
        float dx = start.x - next.x;
        float dy = start.y - next.y;
        float dz = start.z - next.z;
        double distance = 0.0;
        distance = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy + dz * dz);
        return distance;
    }
};

ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const line &ln)
{
    out << "From " << ln.start << " to " << ln.next;
    return out;
}

istream& operator>> (istream& in, line ln)
{
    cout << "Enter x y z start then x y z  next: ";
    in >> ln.start.x >> ln.start.y >> ln.start.z >>  ln.next.x >> ln.next.y >> ln.next.z;
    return in;
}

int main()
{
    point origin, input;
    line ray;
    vector<line> side;

    // READ POINTS FROM FILE
    ifstream pointfile("concave.txt");
    if (pointfile.is_open())
    {
        pointfile >> origin.x >> origin.y >> origin.z;
        cout << "origin: " << origin << endl;
        ray.start = origin;

        while (pointfile >> ray.next)
        {
            cout
                << " GOTO/ " << ray.next 
                << " The distance from point to the next is : "
                << ray.sqDistance() << endl;

            side.push_back(ray);
            ray.start = ray.next; // set start to last end (?)
        }
    }
    else
        cout << "Unable to open file";
    pointfile.close();

    vector<line>::iterator iter = side.begin();
    line temp, closest = *iter;
    float minimumDistance = closest.sqDistance(), distance, sumDistance = 0.0;
    cout << "Line coords" << endl << "distance, Sum of distances, minimum" << endl;
    while(iter != side.end()) {
        closest = *iter;
        distance = closest.sqDistance();
        sumDistance += distance;
        if(minimumDistance > distance) minimumDistance = distance;
        cout << closest << endl
              << distance << " | " << sumDistance << " | " << minimumDistance << endl;
        sumDistance += distance;
        iter++;
    }

    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Sorry for the bug - sum line was there twice - line after cout was an error, also noticed some precision warning - mixed double/float, so switched to double everywhere, now main loop looks like this:

```
vector<line>::iterator iter = side.begin();
line closest = *iter;
double distance, sumOfDistances = 0.0;
cout << "Line coords" << endl << "distance | Sum of distances" << endl;
while (iter != side.end()) {
    closest = *iter;
    distance = closest.sqDistance();
    sumOfDistances += distance;
    cout << closest << endl << distance << " | " << sumOfDistances << endl; // step info output
    iter++;
}
```

Comment: You can accept answer by the check mark under voting buttons, if you also do remember all how to handle all containers. Vector you used is nicely described here for example http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/begin/

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! now I found the distance between point and its next. I still searching the total distance that is the sum of the distance between point and its next. Really your answer is very helpful.

Comment: sumDistance - not the right one ? distance is sum of each segment and sum should sum all of segments. And thanx 4 acceptance ;-)

Comment: yes, the distance not right, because I try to make summation of the last one,then I found the different number of that a I have.anywhere thank you for your help!

Comment: Not sure if it is ok yet, in case let me know - as I am not native in English it is sometimes a bit harder to understand some sentences ;-)

Comment: yeah! you're right!distance is sum of each segment and sum should sum all of segments. I think the problem is that minimum, because the sum is not correct.

Comment: Strange, maybe some math or an example can help - as I checked distance function is called for each pair now, its results summed. Not sure, where could be the problem. Or could you explain or show what is still wrong according to your checks ? (maybe you can edit question and put some explanation there or what results you expect from your or another example)

Comment: The problem was minimum distance. I want only distance and sum distance

Answer (score 0):

Here complete, a bit shorter version including simple results.txt file output.
You can remove 2 lines with comment info output:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

struct point
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};

ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const point &p)
{
    out << "(" << p.x << "," << p.y << " ," << p.z << "," << ")";
    return out;
}

istream& operator>> (istream& in, point& point)
{
    in >> point.x >> point.y >> point.z;
    return in;
}

struct line
{
    point start;
    point next;
    double sqDistance()
    {
        float dx = start.x - next.x;
        float dy = start.y - next.y;
        float dz = start.z - next.z;
        double distance = 0.0;
        distance = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy + dz * dz);
        return distance;
    }
};

ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const line &ln)
{
    out << "From " << ln.start << " to " << ln.next;
    return out;
}

istream& operator>> (istream& in, line ln)
{
    cout << "Enter x y z start then x y z  next: ";
    in >> ln.start.x >> ln.start.y >> ln.start.z >> ln.next.x >> ln.next.y >> ln.next.z;
    return in;
}

int main()
{
    point origin, input;
    line ray;
    vector<line> side;

    // READ POINTS FROM FILE
    ifstream pointfile("concave.txt");
    if (pointfile.is_open())
    {
        pointfile >> origin.x >> origin.y >> origin.z;
        cout << "origin: " << origin << endl;
        ray.start = origin;

        while (pointfile >> ray.next)
        {
            cout
                << " GOTO/ " << ray.next
                << " The distance from point to the next is : "
                << ray.sqDistance() << endl;

            side.push_back(ray);
            ray.start = ray.next; // set start to last end (?)
        }
    }
    else
        cout << "Unable to open file";
    pointfile.close();

    ofstream results("results.txt");
    vector<line>::iterator iter = side.begin();
    line closest = *iter;
    double distance, sumOfDistances = 0.0;
    cout << "Line coords" << endl << "distance | Sum of distances" << endl;
    while (iter != side.end()) {
        closest = *iter;
        distance = closest.sqDistance();
        sumOfDistances += distance;
        results << distance << endl;
        cout << closest << endl << distance << " | " << sumOfDistances << endl; // info output
        iter++;
    }
    results << sumOfDistances << " << Sum" << endl;
    results.close();
    cout << "Complete path distance: " << sumOfDistances << endl; // info output

    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tom thank you very much for your good answer! now my question is answered.

Comment: And sorry for the bug once again - generated probably during copying here(?). Btw in case you do not want to loose reputation, try to learn programming a bit more, but thanx for simple question/answer/acceptance and 15 points ;-) I for example lost some points on each question here.